# I fresh installed Android studio and I am having Gradle Sync error

Tags: android

> Gradle sync failed: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1 available for offline mode.
>                       Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (39 s 571 ms)

Comment: Try disabling the gradle offline sync and download the dependencies.

Comment: Go to build gradle section and disable offline mode and sync project again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Android Studio -> Preferences. Then search for Gradle and uncheck off line work. Then invalidate cache and restart.

[image]